# Определить, какие jpg-файлы битые

Tags: любой-язык, поиск-программ, jpeg

Есть папка с несколькими тысячами jpg-файлов. Потенциально часть из них могла быть повреждена при копировании. Я хочу определить, какие из файлов повреждены. Как это сделать?

Есть идея написать программу, которая пытается создать из файлов bitmap в памяти, но я не уверен в надёжности этого способа.

Comment: пока ждешь, просмотрел бы все уже глазами )

Comment: Быстрый тест Python-скриптом показал, что после замены одного рандомного байта картинка в 90% случаев продолжает успешно читаться

Comment: @teran на [примерно такой картинке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMPEe.jpg) можно случайно не заметить, что она битая)

Comment: @andreymal на такой картинке кроме подсчета хэшсуммы с оригинала и копии ничего не поможет, наверное )

Comment: Сравнить с оригиналом :) Вроде как в JPG контрольной суммы не предусмотрено? P.S. Порылся в описании - таки и в самом деле нет. Так что надежно не получится. Действительно, только пробовать читать и дешифровать, но это в общем случае ничего не гарантирует...